# ASP.net Web Form Routing

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, search-engine

I want to use routing to create a multi-cultured web site.

I was thinking of re-writing the URLs for each language.

Contact Us Page - Example:

```
English:
http://www.domain.com/ContactUs

French:
http://www.domain.com/NousContacter
```

Instead of the traditional way of:

```
English:
http://www.domainname.com/en/contact 

French:
http://www.domainname.com/fr/contact
```

Is this possible to do this without breaking search engines like Google and Yahoo?

Comment: Yes it is possible; I can't give a detailed implemantation but basic concept is  you can write a LanguageFilter based on ActionFilterAttribute and you can keep and change your LanguageCode at requestContext.RouteData.Values.

Comment: Could you elaborate or point me in a direction to do some more research based on your comment above?

Answer (score 0):

I think these samples will help. Seems the first link is more close what I trying to tell.
Hope it helps.

http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx

https://gist.github.com/1583539

Comment: Read through the links.  The solutions are for MVC and not Web Form routing.  I know hot to create the routes, my issues concerns are around search engines. If you read my post again, you will see my original questions.  Thanks for the effort.